# Is ResponsiveSlides working on Safari 9?

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, responsive-slides

I just added responsiveslides to my html and css but it just wont work.
I cant find a mistake in my code so i am very frustrated..

**Could it be, that responsiveslides is not working on Safari 9.1. ?**

So this is the script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script


<script>
$(function() {
$(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
});
</script>
```

this is the html:

```
<div class="bild-links">
    <ul class="rslides">
        <li><img src="mag.jpg" alt="Platzhalter"></li>
        <li><img src="mag-02.jpg" alt="Platzhalter"></li>
        <li><img src="mag-03.jpg" alt="Platzhalter"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

**I would be really really happy if you could help me!**
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you made a typo here...

```
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script <!-- didn't close tag -->
```

Comment: Thanks nobodyshere! I closed that tag, but its still not workin.
Any other suggestions?